# Webdriver does not click at the correct coordinate

Tags: c#, selenium

I am having difficulty with a C# test on a responsive website application. I have four website possibilities. These are two variants of the same code but skinned differently and each variant resizes responsively. My tests use sizes of 1024x768 representing desktop and 420x620 representing mobile. Both desktop tests work flawlessly but one (only one) of the mobile crashes when attempting to click a radio button. I modified my code many times in attempts to find a solution without success; always, three pass but the one mobile crashes. I eventually used the following code to troubleshoot the issue:

```
   public void ClickRadioButton()
    {
        By element = By.Id("radioButtonID");
        IWebElement wait = WaitForElementToAppear(WebDriver, 5000, element);
        int x = wait.Location.X;
        int y = wait.Location.Y;
        wait.Click();
    }
```

With a breakpoint at wait.Click() and examining the coordinate values, wait.Location.X  has a value of 52 and wait.Location.Y has a value of 1596. These coordinates are correct for the location of the radio button but wait.click() fails with the message:

Unexpected error. Element is not clickable at point (58, 6). Other element would receive the click:

I don’t understand why wait.Click() is using these coordinates.

Comment: Can you share the WaitForElementToAppear method you are using?

Comment: As a quick update, the problem has been identified as the radio button element not being in the viewport for just this one rendering of the web page. It is rendered above the top of the view which explains the y-coordinate being reported. None of the well known ways of bringing the element into view work. Setting a breakpoint at the element click() and manually bringing it into view and then stepping forward succeeds but then the next radiobutton fails. I am continuing to research this and hope to present a resolution that will help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it could select radiobutton because it may be an invisible radiobutton that's no longer visible. If you search for multiple radiobuttons, initiate click events on all radiobuttons found and put an 'error handler' for all the radiobuttons found by system, one of them will click on the radiobutton you are looking for.

Also, if the focus is right, instead of doing a .Click event you should replace with a SendKeys("\n") event.

Comment: As a quick update, the problem has been identified as the radio button element not being in the viewport for just this one rendering of the web page. It is rendered above the top of the view which explains the y-coordinate being reported. None of the well known ways of bringing the element into view work. Setting a breakpoint at the element click() and manually bringing it into view and then stepping forward succeeds but then the next radiobutton fails. I am continuing to research this and hope to present a resolution that will help others in the future.